# MVVMLight Messenger message not being received

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a Main viewmodel that holds the main window of the `WPF` application and switches out views in a frame based off of a current viewmodel object. To switch between the viewmodels, I have a `List` of the non-main viewmodels.

```
private IPageViewModel currentPageViewModel;
private List<IPageViewModel> pageViewModels;

//Add pages
PageViewModels.Add(new FirstViewModel(dataService, storageService));
PageViewModels.Add(new SecondViewModel(dataService, storageService));
PageViewModels.Add(new ThirdViewModel(dataService, storageService));

//Set initial page
CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];
```

The first "current" viewmodel object is what loads in when you first pull up the program. I send a message via the `FirstViewModel` and received by the `SecondViewModel`. The problem is, until I at least CHANGE ONCE to the `SecondViewModel`, it doesn't receive the message.

It seems obvious the issue is the `SecondViewModel` isn't instantiated yet to receive the message, but I'm not sure how in the world is it not.

**Bonus info and question...**
Every time I change views/viewmodels, it generates another page...

```
<Frame x:Name="DisplayAreaFrame" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
```

This is where in the `MainWindow.xaml` the view gets changed out.. It doesn't seemingly change out directly though. Instead, it adds a... page(?) that you can flip back and forth from. [image: Navigation Buttons] These buttons only appear once you load in the 2nd or 3rd viewmodels.

Anyway, I'm fresh out of ideas at the moment, so any ideas would be helpful inspirations possibly! Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Added below the SecondViewModel registration

**SecondViewModel registering in contructor**

```
Messenger.Default.Register<String>(this, id => {handleSelectedMessage(id);});
```

Comment: Have you subscribed to the message in the constructor?

Comment: @jannagy02 I apologize... I didn't know I had a comment. I have registered a simple Messenger registration in the constructor. The line is above. Again, it receives the message once I switch to the SecondViewModel once but not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging, the `SecondViewModel` was instantiated TWICE. That made me realize my original `ViewModelLocator` was creating a new instance outside of the above code. Changing the `ViewModelLocator` to instead point to the `MainViewModel`'s instance. :)

Though nobody officially helped, I would like to thank the SO community for helping indirectly! :D